# Are there characters that avoid FOUT (for use with icomoon)?

Tags: css, character, font-face

I'm using [icomoon.io](http://icomoon.io) to convert some SVG files to fonts. The SVGs are graphics, **not** letters. I know this [can be accomplished with JavaScript](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-avoid-fout-by-adding-a-web-font-preloader--webdesign-8287), but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to avoid FOUT (*flash of unstyled text* which occurs before the @font-face file is completely loaded).

**Are there character codes I can assign to my symbols that will be rendered as blank in case the browser temporarily uses a fallback font?**.

Answer (score 1):

About avoiding FOUT have you tried using a DATA-URI approach for loading the font:

http://pagesofinterest.net/blog/2012/08/css-only-fout-prevention/

Also have you tried separating the @font-face embedding it in another css file and load it before the rest of the CSS in which you actually use the custom font?

Ps. For converting SVG to font-icons I usually use Glyphs. http://www.glyphsapp.com/
It allows you to map each single char with your own SVGs and position / rescale them etc.

Comment: upvoted because your answer is informative, but it's not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks, if you create a jsfiddle I'm going to investigate better :)